# Formula to Expire Credit after 1 year

Tags: c#, discrete-mathematics

I am writting a C# website that uses Credit.
A customer will buy $x amount of credit and if it is not used within 12 months it expires.

I cant figure out a mathematic formula to work out how much should be expired?

IE. A customer may buy $50 of credit on june 1/2011. Then spend $40 july 1/2011, then buy another $60 credit April 1/2012

can you help me with a formula I can use to do this?

I can run a service every day to check the credit and date purchased for every customer.

Comment: While it may seem pedantic where there's just a single figure involved, it's a good idea to check with the end user on whether they are LIFO or FIFO on credit purchases so that your algorithm will be consistent with the host organization methodology.

Comment: If credit can expire, you'd always want to spend the oldest credits first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here i can explain you the complete concept for gift vouchers, and additionally i have implemented the same for my project..

Please refer the image below for proper understanding:

[image]

**Steps:**

1. Each user will have gift vouchers stored in database...
2. every user can purchase more than one voucher any time..
3. the logic for deduction on using the voucher..

   Logic is here as per the image

**steps**

1. select each individual voucher based on expiry of the voucher.
2. then take the voucher amount and place a condition if(voucher amount > total purchase) 
   if ($52>$210) = false
3. result is false therefore voucher1 - amount 0 - total purchase variable to $210-$52=$158
4. voucher 1 balance 0 (zero) updated
5. repeat 2,3, 4 for next voucher but total purchase will be $158 now as $52 is already redeemed
6. second voucher is of amount $48 for same condition if($48 > $158) - false $158-$48 = $110
7. update balance to zero for voucher 2 $48 redeemed
8. third voucher is $100 same condition if($100>$110) - false ($110-$100) = $10

if you get any amount greater than voucher amount then eg

voucher amount is $100 and purchased amount is $75 then our if($100>$75) condition will be true 
here you will subtract the amount and update with the balance.. $25 as voucher balance

Coming to your logic of expiry you can run the service daily to check the expiry of each voucher on todays date, if you find any voucher just update the balance to 0 at 12:00 am everyday..

Answer (score 2):

```
balance = (total purchased in last 12 months - total used in last 12 months)
```

Comment: this answer actualy helped me the most. seems quiet obvious now.

Comment: I don't think it's actually correct, though. e.g.: in January, I buy $1. In March, I spend $1. Then, fast forward to February of the next year. My balance should be $0, not $-1.

Comment: @StilesCrisis you are right! thats the reason i had explain the whole logic in my answer, for perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just store a balance in this case--you need to keep a list of all of their credit purchases within the last year, and whenever they spend, you need to deduct from their oldest credit(s).

Note that it's illegal in many states to have gift cards that expire, so be careful with this one!

Comment: Good warning regarding expiring.

Comment: It's not a gift voucher system. and im not in the USA. so its all above board :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to handle this. I've seen everything for a fixed amount expiring (essentially a holding charge - I think many prepaid cards will do this, something like $4 a month, with maybe nothing if you've used it during that month). Others simply take a % of ending balance,  One particular way I like is using simple daily values.

So for simplicity, say you have $100 on day 1, and at day 180 you take out 40, thus have $60 - for the remainder of the year. In this case the formula would be something like

[$100 * (180/365 * (Yearly % Rate))] + [$60 * (185/365 * (Yearly % Rate))]

Just an FYI, but there are typically rules and regulation regarding exactly how these calculations should be done (if allowed at all)